# How to unit-test timeout in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, unit-testing, mocking, flutter-test

I have a facade function that reloads the current firebase user and returns it. The thing is that the user reloading part has a timeout and it needs to be tested.

Function:

```
Future<Option<User>> getSignedInUser() async {
    // Reload currentUser if possible
    // it mustn't throw [TimeoutException] for whole function,
    // this is what this try/catch does
    try {
      await reloadCurrentUser().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString(), name: TAG);
    }
    return optionOf(_auth.currentUser);
  }
```

reloadCurrentUser() function:

```
Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> reloadCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      await _auth.currentUser?.reload();
      return right(unit);
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString(), name: TAG);
      return left(const AuthFailure.userReloadingError());
    }
  }
```

The question is how to test reloadCurrentUser() timeout? I'm trying to throw a TimeoutException when this function is called, but then it throws an error for the whole test.

Current Test function:

```
test(
        'Reaches timeout when reloading currentUser, '
        'throws TimeoutException, but function continues '
        'and returns optionOf currentUser', () async {
      reset(fakeFirebaseAuth);
      reset(fakeFacebookAuth);
      reset(fakeGoogleSignIn);

      final currentUser = FakeUser();

      // It says that currentUser exists and *IS* authenticated
      when(() => fakeFirebaseAuth.currentUser).thenReturn(currentUser);
      when(() => firebaseAuthFacade.reloadCurrentUser())
          .thenThrow(TimeoutException('timeout', const Duration(seconds: 20)));

      final result = await firebaseAuthFacade.getSignedInUser();

      expect(result, isA<Some<User>>());
    });
```

Maybe it's better to remove timeout and use some connectivity package to ensure that the user has a network connection and only then reload the current user?

For testing I'm using [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fake_async](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async) package.

Here's a simple example from their docs that you can modify for your use case:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:fake_async/fake_async.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test("Future.timeout() throws an error once the timeout is up", () {
    // Any code run within [fakeAsync] is run within the context of the
    // [FakeAsync] object passed to the callback.
    fakeAsync((async) {
      // All asynchronous features that rely on timing are automatically
      // controlled by [fakeAsync].
      expect(Completer().future.timeout(Duration(seconds: 5)),
          throwsA(isA<TimeoutException>()));

      // This will cause the timeout above to fire immediately, without waiting
      // 5 seconds of real time.
      async.elapse(Duration(seconds: 5));
    });
  });
}
```